# How do I consume Twitter Streaming API in android using okhttp3?

Tags: java, android, twitter, okhttp, twitter-streaming-api

I want to keep consuming the stream response. This is my code so far. I think I am not able to keep the connection open for long.

```
    OkHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new OkHttpOAuthConsumer("**********",
                "**********");
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret("***********",
                "*************");

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new SigningInterceptor(consumer))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter")
                .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {

                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                Log.d("RESPONSE TWEETS" , responseData);

            }
        });
```

I get the following exception:

```
Callback failure for call to https://stream.twitter.com/...
01-22 13:03:25.238 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:433)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:55)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.java:101)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:62)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:996)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readString(RealBufferedSource.java:189)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:174)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at in.androidlab.twittervisualiser.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:104)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-22 13:03:25.239 27785-28965/in.androidlab.twittervisualiser D/OkHttp:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I also tried with WebSocketListener. I am not getting any response in onMessage()

```
 WebSocketListener listener = new WebSocketListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
                super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
                Log.d("RESPONSE Twitter", response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
                Log.d("RESPONSE Twitter", text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
                super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
                super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
                super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
            }
        };

        WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter is not a websocket call. See https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

You will need to process it as a streaming regular HTTP call.

As documented here https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

> But if the response body is large (greater than 1 MiB), avoid string()
>   because it will load the entire document into memory. In that case,
>   prefer to process the body as a stream.

This is some example code for processing the Response as a stream

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/3757196cde420b9d0fe37cf385b66f4cdafb1ae1/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/output/DownloadHandler.java

```
  @Override public void showOutput(Response response, boolean showHeaders) throws IOException {
    BufferedSource source = response.body().source();

    Sink outputSink = getOutputSink(response);
    try {
      writeToSink(source, outputSink);
    } finally {
      if (!isStdout()) {
        outputSink.close();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void writeToSink(BufferedSource source, Sink out) throws IOException {
    while (!source.exhausted()) {
      out.write(source.buffer(), source.buffer().size());
      out.flush();
  }
```